# ¿Cuál es el tamaño de una variable tipo Date en Java?

Tags: java, date, datetime

Tengo entendido que el problema del `y2k32` va en los tipos de datos que usan nuestras variables, pero no se que tamaño o capacidad aloja una variable de tipo `Date` y por lo tanto no se si estaría propagando el problema.

Comment: En java [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) es una clase y no una variable primitiva. Internamente almacena la marca de hora en milisegundos como una variable primitiva de tipo `long`. En el constructor y en `setDate` podrás ver que su parámetro `date` está descrito como: milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT not to exceed the milliseconds representation for the year 8099. A negative number indicates the number of milliseconds before January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Answer (score 1):

El problema [Y2K38](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_del_a%C3%B1o_2038) afecta principalmente a los sistemas que representan la fecha en base a un entero de 32 bits y, por ello, no pueden representar fechas más allá del año 2038.

La implementación de [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) utliza internamente un [long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) que son 64-bits. Así que no está afectada por este problema.

Si por curiosidad haces la prueba:

```
System.out.println((new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE)));
```

verás que la fecha máxima que se puede crear es del año 292278994:

```
Sun Aug 17 07:12:55 GMT 292278994
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta fue motivo de preocupación hace un tiempo en el homólogo inglés de este sitio.

Por ejemplo [aquí se preguntaba cuando colapsarían las fechas en Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4195027/5587982), o sea, cuando alcanzaríamos un límite máximo.

Como ya respondió @Tobias, no hay por qué preocuparse *por ahora*, puedes usar tus fechas tranquilamente hasta el **17 de agosto del año 292278994**.

Dejo este pequeño programa donde podrás calcular los rangos de fechas entre los que te puedes mover en Java:

**<kbd>[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/JAMX12249)</kbd>**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy G, HH:mm:ss.S Z");
        System.out.println(df.format(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE))); //Mínimo
        System.out.println(df.format(new Date(0))); //Epoch
        System.out.println(df.format(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE))); //Máximo

        
    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
02-12-292269055 BC, 17:47:04.192 +0100
01-01-1970 AD, 01:00:00.0 +0100
17-08-292278994 AD, 08:12:55.807 +0100
```

---

### Conclusión

Mientras no uses fechas anteriores al **2 de Diciembre de 292269055 AC** o superiores al **17 de Agosto de 292278994 DC**, no tendrás ningún problema.